# How to get global variable's value in jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, global-variables

I've declared a static class named Global. In that class I've declared a static string variable LastID. I'm assigning values to this static variable in different web pages. Now I want to get the value of this Global variable in my .aspx page through jQuery. Can you suggest how I can get the value? In my Global class, code looks like this:

```
public static class Global
{
    static string lastID;
    public static string ImportantData
    {
        get
        {
            return lastID;
        }
        set
        {
            lastID = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm assigning value like this:

```
string LID = "MyID";
Global.ImportantData = LID;
```

Now I want to get this Global.ImportantData value with jQuery. How do I do that?

Comment: As an aside, be careful, your static `ImportantData` property will be shared by all the threads in the application pool. Since several pages can be served  in parallel by several threads, assigning to `ImportantData` without proper locking will lead to race conditions and hard-to-diagnose bugs. I'd recommend using something like [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like:

WebForms:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var importantData = '<%= Global.ImportantData %>';
</script>
```

Razor:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var importantData = '@Global.ImportantData';
</script>
```

*Be sure to fully qualify the namespace of Global unless you have included it in your Web.Config.*

**Edit**

In response to the comment, you can also assign it to a hidden field and just parse it out with jQuery as well:

ASPX:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="ImportantData" runat="server" />
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    var importantData = $("#<%= ImportantData.ClientID %>").val();
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ImportantData.Value = Global.ImportantData;
}
```

Comment: hey can we access this variables directly, even if this are initialized on server side class. or is it that we can access on static variables or something, can you explain the concept. As i have used hidden fields on my page to get all the values which ever i need in jQuery.. :(

Comment: Yes, you can.  You "write" it directly to the page and it's parsed with the rest of the javascript.

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo your code for 'web form' was perfect as per my requirement.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.variablename` or in jQuery style `$.variablename` to assign and access global variables

Answer (score 0):

you can use micro-data to store/read stuff from jQuery:

```
<input type="hidden" data-foo="bar" />
```

or you can produce JSON output by your ASP.NET (i.e. globals.aspx) page and than fetch it with ajax/json call and than parse/store/use by your script
oh..  and you can use localStorage or cookies too.

P.S. the last too solutions are less "spaghetti"

Answer (score 0):

In your Page:

```
this.RegisterStartupScript("ImportantData", "var importantData= '" + Global.ImportantData + "';";
```